# Exiting both javascript function embeded in another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function, return

I have a bit of code as below:

```
$(document).on('click', '.set_up_btn', function(){
var menu_name=$('.menu_name').val();
var menu_type=$('.menu_type_sel').val();
var rest_id=$('body').data('rest_id');
var error=false;

if(menu_name=="")
{
    $('.error_box13').eq(0).html("<p>Enter Identifier for this Menu</p>");
    $('.error_box13').eq(0).show(300);
    error=true;
}
if(menu_type=="0")
{
    $('.error_box13').eq(1).html("<p>Select Menu Type</p>");
    $('.error_box13').eq(1).show(300);
    error=true;
}
if(error==true)
{
    return;
}
//check menu name is unique
var data="rest_id="+rest_id+"&name="+menu_name;

$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"includes/check_menu_name.php",
    data:data,
    success:function(html){
        if(html==1)
        {
            //menu name is duplicate
            $('.error_box13').eq(0).html("<p>Menu Name already in use.</p>");
            $('.error_box13').eq(0).show(300);
            error=true;
        }
        else if(html==2)
        {
            //menu name is ok

        }
    return error;
    }
});//end ajax
if(error==true)
{
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return false;
}

var data2="rest_id="+rest_id+"&name="+menu_name+"&menu_type="+menu_type;

$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"includes/set_menu.php",
    data:data2,
    success:function(html2){
        if(html2==1)
        {
            var app="";
            if(menu_type==1)
            {
                menu_type="Bar Menu";
            }
            if(menu_type==2)
            {
                menu_type="Food Menu";
            }
            app+="<h2 class='menu_header'>"+menu_type+"</h2><hr />";
            app+="<h2 class='menu_title'>"+menu_name+"</h2>";
            $(app).appendTo($('.third').eq(2));
        }
        else
        {
            alert("ERROR: Could not write to database. Please try again.");
        }
    }
});//end ajax

});
```

What I need to do is exit the overall 'click' function if the first ajax request returns '1' - the menu name is already in use for this user.

At present if this happens the javascript keeps running into the second ajax request and writes the data to the database.

Comment: AJAX = **Asynchronous** JavaScript and XML

Comment: You cannot do that. The click event handler does not wait for the AJAX request being fired or its callback being executed. Those are asynchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're having this problem because the success function is called at "some later time" when the request returns. It's not instantaneous, so the error variable has not been filled yet. Handle the error inside the success function as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"includes/check_menu_name.php",
    data:data,
    success:function(html){
        if(html==1)
        {
            //menu name is duplicate
            $('.error_box13').eq(0).html("<p>Menu Name already in use.</p>");
            $('.error_box13').eq(0).show(300);
            error=true;


            // we must handle the error here!


            handleError(e, error);
        }
        else if(html==2)
        {
            //menu name is ok



            // continue on as normal
            continueNoError();
        }
    return error;
    }
});//end ajax

// Code run here runs BEFORE $.ajax returns


function handleError(e, error) {
    if(error==true)
    {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        return false;
    }
}

function continueNoError() {
    // Put what to after the first ajax call here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently the second AJAX call will run whatever happens.

Wrap it in a method inside your click that you call when requirements are satisfied.

i.e:

```
if (menu_type === 2) {
    menu_type="Food Menu";
    setMenu();
}
```

then:

```
var setMenu = function () {
    $.ajax({
        // do stuff
    });
}
```